# Receiving Email Problem from outside in Elastix

Tags: email, postfix

I've already installed elastix 3 stable version (postfix, cyrus sasl2).
I'm using as email server in my local network. here everything works as the bellow:

- Send    Email from Local To Local      = **OK!**
- Send    Email from Local To Outside    = **OK!**
- Receive Email (that Sent from Local)   = **OK!**
- Receive Email (that **Sent** from **Outside**) = **NO!**  ***

In fact the just problem i couldn't get email that send from outside in my inbox however i can already receive the mails that sent from local network in my inbox.
I'm afraid whats the wrong with the problem. but I would appreciate if anyone can help me during this problem. the master.cf and main.cf file are also as the bellow, I don't know if i should any other configuration.
also note that **it seems my ISP Blocks port 25**, so Im using another port as smtp.

etc/postfix/**Main.cf** (almost without comment)

```
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    command_directory = /usr/sbin
    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
    mail_owner = postfix
    myhostname = mail.cqnordica.com
    mydomain = cqnordica.com
    myorigin = $mydomain
    inet_interfaces = all
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
    mynetworks_style = class
    mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
    debug_peer_level = 2
    debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
    setgid_group = postdrop
    html_directory = no
    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
    sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.5.6/samples
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.5.6/README_FILES
    virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
    virtual_mailbox_domains = cqnordica.com
    # added by myself 
    smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    #smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
            permit_mynetworks,
            permit_sasl_authenticated,
            reject_unauth_destination
```

etc/postfix/**Master.cf** (almost without comment)

```
    # Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
    # of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
    #
    # Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
    #
    # ==========================================================================
    # service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
    #               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
    # ==========================================================================
    2599      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    #  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    #628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
    pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
    qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
    #qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
    tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
    rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
    bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
    flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
    proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
    proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
    smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    # When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
    relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
    #       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
    showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
    error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
    retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
    discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
    local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
    virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
    lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
    anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
    scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is not about mail-server infact. it seems Port 25  **should be open** for *receiving mails from outside*. **without this, it doesn't work**. I have already seen something about it in other forums too, but i couldn't bleave how important it is. once it was unblocked, the outside emails received well. Just i want to share my solution and answer that i got. :)